# What's a difference between indexing document after creating an index mapping AND creating an document directly with indexing in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm confused with mapping and indexing. As I know, mapping a index is make kinda a schema of document.

My point is when I'm creating a document, there are several ways.

1) mapping an index -> indexing documents

2) when creating documents, simultaneously mapping would be done.

then, why do I have to do a mapping for some cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch allows to not define mapping for fields because it has some options to detect field types and apply its default mapping. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html
It's good practice to always default mapping explicitly, relying on ES algorithm can cause unpredictable results.

If you really need some dynamic mappings because for example you don't know all required fields while defining mapping you can use something like dynamic templates or default mapping.

Comment: It's really true that I have to be clear about default mappings. Back then, I wasn't understanding about types. As a result, I faced a lot of problems when I was querying. I better have a habit to make a mapping first.

Answer (score 0):

There are several known limitations with default mappings (like text is defaulted to keyword and anything above 256 bytes is ignored). That might work for most of the cases where data is from log. But having a mapping type allows you more control on what kind of indexing to be done and whether to index a field or not. Depending on your use case, the preferred option (defining mapping vs on the fly mapping) might be different.

Comment: Exactly!!! when I use all default mapping, I would face some problems. I definitely have to practice and be familiar with mappings! Thank you.